# Always-on Internet connection does not load some sites, while Bridge mode does

Tags: internet, modem

I have a D-Link modem and I have set it up to connect to the Internet automatically, i.e. `Always-on` connection.

Now my problem is that some site don't load while others load perfectly fine. But if I open up a command prompt and ping any website that was not loading in the browser, it works (ping returns with response from the site). I have tested all the browsers, so as to rule out the possibility of a browser malfunctioning.

More importantly, when I switch to `Bridge mode` in my modem settings, **ALL** the sites load perfectly. The ones that were not loading earlier also do.

Why is this the case. What can I do to solve this problem.

Things I have tried...

- Flush my DNS cache
- Remove all unwanted items from `msconfig` Startup tab
- Tried setting my DNS servers to Google DNS (`8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4`) and [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/opendns-ip-addresses)
- resetting my modem to factory config. and then reconfiguring it again

Answer (score 0):

Just because a website returns a ping has nothing to do with the site functioning correctly (or as you are expecting).

If a site isn't loading on your set up but is from work or another PC (try your mobile phone on 3G as this will not use your router) then the answer is likely to be router (firewall/black list/parent control) or maybe your ISP blocks the site.

Comment: but if my ISP blocked the sites, why would they all load in the `bridge mode`

Comment: OK - so you know the fault - it's a setting on the router!